# (React Native) Render error Value is undefined expected object

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript, react-native-reanimated

So I was making a todo app and i encountered an error

**Error**

```
Render Error
Value is undefined expected object
```

[image]

**Code of Main.tsx**

```
<Center _dark={{bg: 'blueGray.900'}} _light={{bg: 'blueGray.50'}} px={4} flex={1}>
<VStack space={5} alignItems="center">
         <Box w="100px" h="100px">
            <AnimatedCheckBox />
         </Box>
          <Box p={10} bg={useColorModeValue('red.500', 'yellow.500')}>
            <Text>
              Hello World
            </Text>
          </Box>
          <ThemeToggle />
          </VStack>
      </Center>
```

**and the code of the Animated Check Box Component**

[image]

Does anyone knows what is causing this error. If you do plz do tell me with the solution it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are code is correct, then you need open tab for center is missing.

```
<Center>
<VStack space={5} alignItems="center">
         <Box w="100px" h="100px">
            <AnimatedCheckBox />
         </Box>
          <Box p={10} bg={useColorModeValue('red.500', 'yellow.500')}>
            <Text>
              Hello World
            </Text>
          </Box>
          <ThemeToggle />
          </VStack>
      </Center>
```